# How to make Checkstyle ignore missing JavaDoc whenever there is a specific annotation

Tags: java, checkstyle

I want to customize the Checkstyle [JavadocVariable](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_javadoc.html) rule, so that it does not complain about a field that is has a `@FindBy` annotation.

```
class Demo{

    @FindBy(id = "new-button")
    public WebElement createButton;  //<- no JavaDoc required because it is a field "injected" by selenium

    public String otherField;    //<- complain about missing Java doc
}
```

But I do not have a clue how to specify this in the `checkstyle.xml` file. Does anybody have an idea?

*Things that does not work in this use case:*

- *Modifyng the checked class is also no solution!*
- `SuppressWithNearbyCommentFilter` *will not work, because it is a annotation but not a comment*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I know several solutions but all of them requires additional work to do.

1. Implementing own `JavadocVariableCheck` with possibility to skip check in case annotation is provided.
2. Implementing checkstyle filter (like `SuppressWarningsHolder` + `SuppressWarningsFilter` but with annotation support)
3. Or implement simple filter which scans for `@FindBy` and ignores two lines after it.

My solution (the simplest one):

```
package org.aap.checks;

import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
import com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.AuditEvent;
import com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.AutomaticBean;
import com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.FileContents;
import com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.Filter;
import com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.FileContentsHolder;

import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class SuppressWithAnnotationFilter
        extends AutomaticBean
        implements Filter {

    public class Tag implements Comparable<Tag> {
        private final int firstLine;
        private final int lastLine;

        public Tag(int firstLine, int lastLine) {
            this.firstLine = firstLine;
            this.lastLine = lastLine;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Tag other) {
            if (firstLine == other.firstLine) {
                return lastLine - other.lastLine;
            }
            return (firstLine - other.firstLine);
        }

        public boolean isMatch(AuditEvent event) {
            final int line = event.getLine();
            return line >= firstLine && line <= lastLine;
        }

        @Override
        public final String toString() {
            return "Tag[lines=" + firstLine + " to " + lastLine + "]";
        }
    }

    private final List<Tag> tags = Lists.newArrayList();
    private WeakReference<FileContents> fileContentsReference =
            new WeakReference<FileContents>(null);

    public FileContents getFileContents() {
        return fileContentsReference.get();
    }

    public void setFileContents(FileContents fileContents) {
        fileContentsReference = new WeakReference<FileContents>(fileContents);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean accept(AuditEvent event) {
        if (event.getLocalizedMessage() == null) {
            return true;        // A special event.
        }

        final FileContents currentContents = FileContentsHolder.getContents();
        if (currentContents == null) {
            return true;
        }
        if (getFileContents() != currentContents) {
            setFileContents(currentContents);
            tagSuppressions();
        }
        for (final Iterator<Tag> iter = tags.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
            final Tag tag = iter.next();
            if (tag.isMatch(event)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void tagSuppressions() {
        tags.clear();
        final FileContents contents = getFileContents();

        String[] contentsLines = contents.getLines();
        for (int i = 0; i < contentsLines.length; i++) {
            if (contentsLines[i].contains("@FindBy")) {
                tags.add(new Tag(i+1, i+2));
            }
        }

        Collections.sort(tags);
    }
}
```

Add resulting class into classpath of the checkstyle task then in `checkstyle.xml` specify filter:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC
    "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Check Configuration 1.3//EN"
    "http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/configuration_1_3.dtd">
<module name="Checker">
  <module name="TreeWalker">
    ....
    <!-- your Check goes here -->
    <module name="org.aap.checks.SuppressWithAnnotationFilter"/>
    ....
  </module>
</module>
```